# Maintain aspect ratio box that cannot create vertical scrollbars and not clip

Tags: html, css

**Question:**
How can I ensure that my video maintains aspect ratio (16x9) and will not create scrollbars on very small height viewports and not clip.

**Recreate:**

Make the browser window very wide and very short by using the bottom edge and you will see the window now has a scrollbar.

```css
.wrapper {
  background: green;
  height: 100%;
  width: 50%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  
}
.video {
  background: red;
  overflow: hidden;
  max-height: 0;
  padding-top: 56.25%;
}
```

```html
  <div class="wrapper">
    <div class="video">123</div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can consider a `max-width` that you define based on the `vh` unit:

```css
.wrapper {
  background: green;
  height: 100%;
  width: 50%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  max-width: 160vh; 
  /* the 56.25% of this value should be less or equal to 100vh considering margin/padding/border
  
    In this case with 8px of body margin the max value should be:
     calc((100vh - 16px)*100/56.25)   
  */
}

.video {
  background: red;
  overflow: hidden;
  max-height: 0;
  padding-top: 56.25%;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="video">123</div>
</div>
```

Comment: @MatthewHarwood added some maths if you want accurate calculation ;)